# Any reason why numpy's linspace does not support a dtype specification?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was wondering why `numpy.linspace` does not have the option dtype, as for example `numpy.array`, `numpy.zeros` or `numpy ones`. Is there a reason for this and can it for this be that it is better to use `numpy.array` if I know that I will use a given data type?

**Edit:** Ok, I think I get it: `linspace` by default creates a float array - which kinda makes scence as the intervalls would not always support another data type. Apart from this, is there another fundamental difference between an array created by `linspace` and `np.array([N], dtype=float)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, apart obviously for the content of the array.

Checking the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/core/function_base.py#L8) of `linspace`, it creates the array using `arange`. `arange` returns an array of integers, then cast to float by the multiplication by `step`, which is a float.

On the other hand, `arange` ([link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)) allows to choose the `dtype`. If you want to 'create' a `linspace` of a different `dtype`, you can adapt the code of `linspace` and pass to `arange` a different `dtype`.

Comment: If you look at the source code you linked carefully, you will see that what gets returned from `arange` is an array of integers, that gets converted to floating point when it is multiplied by the floating point `step`.